# How to add products in cart and wishlist with external code outside Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, session, magento-connect

How can I add products with PHP to the customer's cart. Having customer's id and login details.

The login is successful. Just need to update the cart with the products, quantity and prices that user can also check from the magento site also.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way? Just fire a ajax request to the page.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring

```
/path/to/magento/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]
```

Maybe you have a problem with the SameOriginPolicy with JS, so you might use an iframe or image instead.

Comment: Sir with ajax i did but after that I am not able to retrieve the list of products using Mage.

Answer (score 0):

The API would work well for this.

Supports SOAP and REST.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: I read about this yesterday but couldn't see how I define the customer or his cart to put things into, how does this work?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt the checkout api has cart_customer.set and cart_product.add.  You can fetch customer data with the customer api and set it with the checkout api.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/checkout.html.  Hope this helps.